# go collection list, how to pass list in to function?

Tags: go

```
package main
// You are given two linked lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

// Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
// Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    l1 := list.New()
    l1.PushBack(4)
    l1.PushBack(5)
    l1.PushBack(2)

    l2 := list.New()
    l2.PushBack(7)
    l2.PushBack(3)

    l3 := list.New()
    l3 = addTwoNumbers(l1, l2)

    for e := l3.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }
}
func addTwoNumbers(l1 list, l2 list) (l3 list) {
    int carry = 0
    l4 := list.New()
    e1 := l1.Front()
    e2 := l2.Front()
    for ;; {
        int sum = carry
        if l1 != nil {
            sum += l1.Value
            l1 = l1.Next()
        }
        if l2 != nil {
            sum += l2.Value
            l2 = l2.Next()
        }
        l4.PushBack(sum % 10)
        carry = sum / 10

        if l1== nil && l2 == nil && carry == 0{
            break
        }
    }
    return l4
}
```

I got error:

```
./addTwoNumbers.go:26: syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }
./addTwoNumbers.go:31: syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }
```

But I dont know how to fix it. need help. thanks

Comment: One thing I have noticed about your code is the improper int declartions of `carry` and `sum` in your function `addTwoNumbers`. Normally you use `var carry int` and similar for sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of errors in your code.

- when importing list, list is the module name not the type. use list.List
- in go the type is `after` the name of the variable. most of the time you don't need to declare it
- when iterating over the list use element not list. Element has `Value`

Here is a working version

http://play.golang.org/p/yys-OcxZz2

```
package main

// You are given two linked lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

// Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
// Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    l1 := list.New()
    l1.PushBack(4)
    l1.PushBack(5)
    l1.PushBack(2)

    l2 := list.New()
    l2.PushBack(7)
    l2.PushBack(3)

    l3 := list.New()
    l3 = addTwoNumbers(l1, l2)

    for e := l3.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }
}
func addTwoNumbers(l1 *list.List, l2 *list.List) (l3 *list.List) {
    carry := 0
    l4 := list.New()
    e1 := l1.Front()
    e2 := l2.Front()
    for {
        sum := carry
        if e1 != nil {
            sum += e1.Value.(int)
            e1 = e1.Next()
        }
        if e2 != nil {
            sum += e2.Value.(int)
            e2 = e2.Next()
        }
        l4.PushBack(sum % 10)
        carry = sum / 10

        if e1 == nil && e2 == nil && carry == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
    return l4
}
```

Comment: Also you can write the func like this `addTwoNumbers(l1, l2 *list.List)`, right?

Comment: thank @fabrizioM BTW, i remembered I read a article saying foo( l1 list.List) is equivalent to foo(l1 *list.List) they all pass by reference. I don't know if that is true?

Comment: BTW, can I modify l3 in function, instead of new-ing a new list l4? I tried but I got null pointer exception. Don't know why.

Comment: @BufBills make a new question, and show what you have tried!